# Are there issues with MS Graph API CalendarView when querying 149+ days?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a graph api that, to spare you details, updates a calendar with events and removes duplicates.

I have events from the source data that are be shown as existing when the code decides whether or not to add it.

If I run 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/somecal@someco/calendarView' with a date in the header, I get a response showing it exists.  However, when I log into the calendar via Outlook, it is definitely not there.

This only seems to be affecting some items that are around 149 days out.

It updates about 250 days worth of data, with probably 1000 http requests per run.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh! When querying All Day events, be sure not to list the TIME in the date time format of the parameters!